# Smart App Banner Not Displaying for Uninstalled App

Tags: ios, safari, app-store, mobile-safari, smart-app-banner

I'm experiencing an issue with the Smart App Banner on my website, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. I have followed Apple's guidelines for implementing the Smart App Banner on my website, but it doesn't seem to work as expected when the app is not installed on the user's device.

Here are the details of my setup:

I have added the following meta tag to the root index file of my website: html

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=, app-argument=myapp.com">
```

In the .well-known folder, I have created an apple-app-site-association file with content like this:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "HGU83XXXXX.com.myapp.app",
        "paths": ["*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the Smart App Banner only displays with the "Open" button when the app is already installed on the user's device. However, when the app is not installed, the Smart App Banner doesn't appear to prompt users to download the app from the App Store.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to make the Smart App Banner work correctly, especially when the app is not installed on the user's device. Are there any specific steps or configurations I might be missing in this implementation?

Thank you for your assistance!